# Is it possible to add files to classpath for testing and how

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

My project is Java & Maven based. I have a properties file under src/main/resources so when I try to do MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertyFileName) everything loads fine. My understanding is that as long as I have the property file in classpath it should get picked up.

My goal here is to write a unit test where I can test this out. I know in Spring framework there are classpath load apis that let you pick up any file and add it to the classpath during testing. I am not using Spring here so what is the best way for me to create a properties file in memory, and it to classpath for the duration of the test?

Pseudo steps:

- begin method
- create file in memory with properties
- add file to classpath
- print properties
- end method

I am using Eclipse. Thanks in advance.

Update - I am trying to add a file to classpath on the fly because a jar may be run from command line or a second file in the resources might override the default props file

Comment: So you are basically want to test `getResourceAsStream` method? It is tested elsewhere and you shouldn't do that. :)

Comment: Why are other people's comments disappearing from this page?

Comment: It will work if you copy the file to src/test/resources directory.

under testing, target/test-classes directory is added to class path and junit will copy all file in test/resource directory to target/test-classes.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Why add a file to classpath for testing only if it would not be referenced by production code? If it overrides an existing file or would just be used by the test use `src/test/resources`.

Comment: @JohnB see update above.

Comment: Wouldn't having this second file in the /src/test/resources and verify that it's values are used test this? What you are doing is a very common pattern and people put files in /stc/test/resources all the time that override properties set in production. I have not heard of anything trying to test this further.

Comment: Ok well sounds like src/test/resources is sufficient. Thanks John

Comment: But what if I want to have different files on the classpath for different tests? And I want to test the behaviour when they're there/not present, I am not testing getResourceAsStream()!